# How to show the hidden application window which hid/minimized by ctrl+h/m on mac

Tags: macos, hidden, applicationwindow

> How to show/re-display the hidden application window which hided/minimized by ctrl+h/m etc in mac?

I just don't like click the application icon on the dock!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I just had found the keyboard shortcuts few minutes ago.
For chinese, [这是答案](http://www.xitongzhijia.net/xtjc/20150115/34948.html)

OK,here we go:

1. Press `Command+Tab` or `Command+Shift+Tab`to switching to the hidden application you want to show again;
2. Holding `Command` key, release others(`Tab` or `Shift+Tab`);
3. Keep Holding `Command` unless I tell you to release it , **AND** press `Option` key;
4. Release the `Command`! Do it now! Don't hesitate,Just Do it right now! **BUT**        one more thing--**Holding** the `Option` key.
5. Get your hands off your desk and we're DONE!